# Gitlab with Azure AD auth

Tags: azure, gitlab

So I'm trying to auth my GitLab with the Azure AD auth.

This is my `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
`gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['azure_oauth2']
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_sync_email_from_provider'] = 'saml'
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_sync_profile_from_provider'] = ['saml']
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_sync_profile_attributes'] = ['email']
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_sign_in_with_provider'] = 'saml'
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = true
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_saml_user'] = false
# gitlab_rails['omniauth_external_providers'] = ['twitter', 'google_oauth2']
gitlab_rails['sync_profile_from_provider'] = ['azure_oauth2']
gitlab_rails['sync_profile_attributes'] = ['name', 'email', 'location']
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
  {
    "name" => "azure_oauth2",
    "args" => {
      "client_id" => "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "client_secret" => "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb=",
#    "args" => { "access_type" => "offline", "approval_prompt" => "" }
      "tenant_id" => "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
    },
#    "base_azure_url" => "https://login.microsoftonline.com"
  }
]
```

In my azure portal, I have this config:

Azure AD Free

One app in the Azure AD Free.

I have the reply URL to http://myaplicationdomain/auth/oauth2_generic and also http://myappauth.com/users/auth/azure_oauth2/callback

When i try to login with the azure auth I received the following error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:

So I just want to know if somebody else tried this and have some solution.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

There's no bundler because is an Azure installation.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your app registration information, but from the error message you're sharing it looks like the Reply Url configured for the app registration doesn't match the reply Url you're passing with your request. A few ideas from someone who hasn't used Gitlab before.

Watch this video which specifically addresses reply url configuration in Azure: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9U1VGyztEM&t=9s

Use fiddler or some other proxy to see what value you're sending to the Azure endpoint for the redirect_uri parameter. It'll need to match a configured reply url in the app.

Finally, [refer to this article](http://packetperception.org/gitlab-auth-azure.html) which suggests that you need to configure a well-known redirect url in the app registration following the format `https://mygitlab.mycorp.org/users/auth/azure_oauth2/callback`

Comment: Thank you very much, Josh, I'll try this and give you a feedback.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, but I cannot figure out what the redirect_uri parameter is set to when the request is made. Any hints on how to find this? I tried using Fiddler Everywhere, but I didn't see any redirect_uri parameters being sent.

Comment: I actually ended up finding it in the address bar.