# How to implement a central OIDC provider between Gitlab-ci job and cloud providers for pipeline OIDC authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, gitlab, google-oauth, openid-connect

I search a way to implement a way to centralize authentication between Gitlab-ci and my cloud providers AWS / gcp / azure.

Gitlab provide  links https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/cloud_services/aws/ for all hyperscaler but i would like to have more central control and provide the capacity to all of my teams to call a unique url and create specific logic ( project path , branch , providers oidc workflow ... )  in another central tool.

do you have any ideas ?

all of gitlab documentation working fine but i don't want to expose this complexity to my teams , i would like to provide more abstractions if possible

Comment: The simplest form of authentication is to create an Azure Ad app and authenticate it with your gitlab pipeline as given here- https://dev.to/erudinsky/how-to-deploy-to-azure-with-gitlab-authentication-credentials-store-runner-config-yaml-pipeline-example-37bp Additionally you can refer this SO thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727215/gitlab-with-azure-ad-auth and this oauth document on azure and gitlab - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/azure.html#

Comment: You can also watch this video -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/devops-lab/gitlab-into-azure

Comment: the problem is easy to resolve when you think one hyperscaler by one hyperscaler , and when you have 10 repository , i thinx X500 pipeline , i want to use a very similar way across cloud providers if possible

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no centralized repository for now to store all your Authentication secrets and parameters for multiple cloud providers, But As a workaround, You can make use of Gitlab variables:-

> - `Protected:`  Used in protected branches and tags
> - `Masked:`  Hidden in logs, Can be used for Client-secret ID's.
> - `Expanded:`  Variables with  `$`  will act as the start of a reference to another variable.

Instead of hard-coding the variables in my pipeline repository file like below:-

[image]

Add the variable at the gitlab settings level for various cloud providers and reference it to your gitlab pipeline script for multiple hyperscalers like below:-

***Added variable in the Settings > CICD > Variables > Add variable >***

[image]

[image]

***And reference it in your pipeline scripts like below:-***

***.gitlab-ci.yml***

```
deploy-job:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  variables:
    appId: $client_id
    password: $client_secret
    tenant: $tenant_id
    subId: $subscription_id
  stage: deploy
  script:
```